# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a link problem with my CSS and JS files in codeSearch.html file. I have seen some answers in stackoverflow,  but I still do not know where I am wrong.

Here is my code: 
[image: link code]

my directory 
[image: my directory]

Comment: The template's paths will be relative to where you include the template, not from where the template's document is.

Comment: `I have a link problem with my CSS and JS files` - can you describe in more detail what you mean. What do you expect, what do you observe instead, are there any developer tools console errors

Comment: Hi Scott, could you please tell me the correct path? I did not get your meaning.

Comment: Hi Jaromanda, the problem is that the server cannot find my JS and CSS file. I think it is due to my wrong link.

Comment: If it's up and running, use your browser to attempt to navigate to the .js and .css files. That can help you quickly/interactively find out where they are actually located when the app is running.

Comment: @YanjuanDuan If you're including `codeSearch.html` in a file way up the hierarchy, you'll need to provide the relative path from the location the file will be parsed, or use an absolute path.  The problem is likely that `../codeSearch.css` doesn't exist from where the file is being parsed.

Comment: Hi @mmcrae, could you teach me how to use browser to navigate to the JS and CSS file? I am new to this filed and do not know how to do this. I am using OS X EI and Safari.

Comment: @YanjuanDuan - try things like `localhost:portnumber/approot/js/codeSearch.js` etc. Unfortunately, it's impossible for us to know why your setup isn't working, with the information given. We don't know how you're deploying/running the app etc. So my suggestion is to fiddle around with the url like above

Comment: @ScottKaye sorry, I don't quite get it. Is it possible for you to write down the correct code or do you need more information?

Answer (score 0):

which kind of your DTD, if it's not !DOYTYPE html, you should add type property to your link tag

Comment: yeah, I use !DOYTYPE html

Comment: @jelly welcome to stackoverflow..! your answer should be well formatted..and if you are not sure ask in comment and then answer..